# How does Visual Studio 2012 reference jquery in ScriptManager?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, scriptmanager

I created a new Azure Cloud Service Web Role in Visual Studios 2012.  Included in the Site.Master page is the ScriptManager:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

There is also a scripts folder in the solution containing:

```
_references.js
jquery-1.7.1.intellisense.js
jquery-1.7.1.js
jquery-1.7.1.min.js
jquery-ui-1.8.20.js
jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js
modernizer-2.5.3.js
```

So far, I have not been able to figure out how the ScriptManager makes reference to jquery and jquery-ui based only on the name provided.  Could anyone provide insight to where this reference is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default packages that come with Visual Studio 2012 registers the names jquery and jquery.ui.combined with ScriptManager. Script Manager then replaces it with reference to the actual jquery Scripts in the CDN[if you set  EnableCDN=true]. If you dont set this it will pick up from the directories you mentioned.

You can find more details here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2012/09/21/asp-net-4-5-scriptmanager-improvements-in-webforms.aspx

If you do a view source of your webpage, you will see the references to the script.